# Why won't my form return matching results unless I change the value text?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Thanks in advance for your help! In my Ruby on Rails application, my search form returns results except for when I use a specific option from my dropdown field. This option returns no results but should.

Setup: Rails 2.3X / MySQL database. The form pulls results from a MySQL table called "Masterlocations", which has a column called geo_region. I'm trying to do a basic look-up of records by geo_region. It works for every option in my dropdown EXCEPT for "New England CT ME MA NH RI VT"

Here's the form field in question:

```
    <p><label for="region">Region</label>
    <select id="geo_region" name="search[geo_region]">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="Far West AK CA HI NV OR WA">Far West AK CA HI NV OR WA</option>
    <option value="Great Lakes IL IN MI OH WI">Great Lakes IL IN MI OH WI</option>
    <option value="Mid East DE DC MD NJ NY PA">Mid East DE DC MD NJ NY PA</option>
    <option value="New England CT ME MA NH RI VT">New England CT ME MA NH RI VT</option>
    <option value="Plains IA KS MN MO NE ND SD">Plains IA KS MN MO NE ND SD</option>
    <option value="Rocky Mountains CO ID MT UT WY">Rocky Mountains CO ID MT UT WY</option>
    <option value="Southeast AL AR FL GA KY LA MS NC SC TN VA WV">Southeast AL AR FL GA KY LA MS NC SC TN VA WV</option>
    <option value="Southwest AZ NM OK TX">Southwest AZ NM OK TX</option>
    <option value="US Service schools">US Service schools</option>
    </select>
```

**What I've Tried:**

I changed the option to read: "New England CT" and changed one of the values in the database to match. Still doesn't work.

THEN, I changed the option to read: "New England" and changed one of the values in the database to match. THAT works, but I don't know why and I'd prefer to avoid changing all of the database values.

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: We're gonna need a lot more information... what's in the DB, what you're using to hit the DB, how you're generating this form, etc.  If the form is hard coded, maybe you should just pull the records from the DB when you're generating the form, that way they'll always matched.

Comment: What DB Query are you using to call the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to write this as a comment, but its too big:

---

IMO, you'd be better giving your `<select>` a list of `id`'s, which you can then reference in the Rails controller, like this:

```
#view
<select id="geo_region" name="search[geo_region]">
    <option value=""> </option>
    <option value="0">Far West AK CA HI NV OR WA</option>
    <option value="1">Great Lakes IL IN MI OH WI</option>
    <option value="2">Mid East DE DC MD NJ NY PA</option>
    <option value="3">New England CT ME MA NH RI VT</option>
    <option value="3">Plains IA KS MN MO NE ND SD</option>
    <option value="4">Rocky Mountains CO ID MT UT WY</option>
    <option value="5">Southeast AL AR FL GA KY LA MS NC SC TN VA WV</option>
    <option value="6">Southwest AZ NM OK TX</option>
    <option value="7">US Service schools</option>
</select>
```

That will allow you to use the passed ID's to create a query from an array or similar:

```
#controller
def your_method
    regions = Model.regions
    #db call here
end

#model
def self.regions
    regions = []
    regions << %w(Far West AK CA HI NV OR WA)
    regions << %w(Great Lakes IL IN MI OH WI)
    regions << %w(Mid East DE DC MD NJ NY PA)
    regions << %w(Plains IA KS MN MO NE ND SD)
    regions << %w(Rocky Mountains CO ID MT UT WY)
    regions << %w(Southeast AL AR FL GA KY LA MS NC SC TN VA WV)
    regions << %w(Southwest AZ NM OK TX)
    regions << %w(US Service schools)
    regions
end
```